# Html element falls outside of viewport

Tags: html, css

I test my site by google speed tools and get me this error for mobile devices that

> the element falls outside the viewport

I test this by this code :

```
$('#divBackTabs').innerWidth()-$(window).innerWidth()
```

this code returned **13**.
I try to set max-width but do not solved.

How to force `#divBackTabs` element that **max-width** of it be 100%.

[My WebSite](https://travelenter.com)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should paste a sample of your HTML and CSS.

but in your case I see that you are using bootstrap so the `.row` element get `-15px` margin that put it outside the viewport. and then the col-12 using padding `15px`.
just remove the the `col-12` class and delete the parent `.row` div.

it will stay inside the viewport after that.